# Additional information: Complex DataBinding accepts as a data source either an IList or an IListSource

Tags: c#, list

I'm trying to select sum of total in excel sheets and add it into a list box, each one of them in a new line.

```
private void btn_update_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    for (int i = list_sheetnames.Items.Count -1; i >= 0; i--) {
        string connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + textBox_filename.Text + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 XML;HDR=YES;';";
        string selectCmd = "Select SUM(Total) As Total_SUM From [" + list_sheetnames.Items[i] + "$]";

        using(OleDbConnection excelConn = new OleDbConnection(connString)) {
          excelConn.Open(); 
          OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(selectCmd, excelConn);
          OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
          DataTable sheetInfo = new DataTable();
          da.Fill(sheetInfo);

          //Do something with the data.
          //list_total.Items.Add(sheetInfo);
          list_total.DataSource = da.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I got an error

Comment: which error do you get?

Comment: I rewrote your question a little, please include the error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to bind a datatable to a List. I'm guessing List_total is a `List<string>`? If you want to add the values from the datatable then you'll need to loop through the rows and the items to get what you want.

```
foreach (var row in da.Rows)
{
    foreach (var item in row.ItemArray)
    {
        //do your checks on the data here and add it to your list if necessary.
        list_total.Add(item.ToString());
    }
}
```

You could also try the traditional for loop like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < da.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    list_total.Add(da.Rows[i]["Total_SUM"].ToString());
}
```

***UPDATE***
So your code is now:

```
List<string> lst = new List<string>(); 

foreach (DataRow r in sheetInfo.Rows) 
{ 
    string sheettotal = (string)r["Total_SUM"].ToString();
    lst.Add(sheettotal); 
}

list_total.DataSource = lst;
```

Comment: i didn't get it, could you please make it clear i mean where can i add this code and how can i configure it

Comment: @AbdullazizHappy - at the point where you do 'list_total.DataSource = da.ToString();'. You can't add a datatable as a datasource to a list. Instead you need to add the individual entries to the list by going through the datatable.

Comment: row.ItemArray is not available 

here is the edited code

 DataTable sheetInfo = new DataTable();
                    da.Fill(sheetInfo);
                    string total=sheetInfo.ToString();
               
                   

                    foreach (var row in sheetInfo.Rows)
                    {
                        foreach (var item in row.ToString())
                        {
                           
                            list_total.Items.Add(item.ToString());
                        }
                    }

Comment: @AbdullazizHappy - row.ToString() won't work. You need iterate over the items within the row.

Comment: @AbdullazizHappy - updated my answer with an alternative solution.

Comment: i change my code into this and its working but only the last Total_SUM i have 3 sheets in the workbook its only get the last total sum by tracing the code its working v.good but replace any old value with the new one 
http://i.imgur.com/9pyov3u.jpg

List<string> lst = new List<string>();
                    foreach (DataRow r in sheetInfo.Rows)
                    {
                        string sheettotal = (string)r["Total_SUM"].ToString();
                        lst.Add(sheettotal);
                        
                    }
                    list_total.DataSource = lst;

Comment: @AbdullazizHappy - I've updated my answer to show your current code. Have you tried debugging and seeing what happens through each iteration of the loop? So what does lst contain after each iteration?